# Yahoo! email transliteration from English to Thai

Tags: yahoo-mail

Someone asked me if he could email from Yahoo-mail using transliteration from English to Thai (I know this is possible in Gmail).
I couldn't convince him to change his email to Gmail, (not being very computer literate)-I want to solve this for him.

OR

rather the question in a different way - This Thai person wants to email his relatives in Thailand and wants to use Yahoo! for his email. What is the "free" way to get this done?

Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

Google and MSN translate.

Answer (score 2):

If he is using Windows then I guess [Google Input Method](http://www.google.com/ime/transliteration/) would work.